# Transiting at Kuala Lumpur

Tags: transit, kul

I'm traveling from New Delhi, India, to Bangkok, Thailand via Kuala Lumpur on Malaysia Airlines.

I have stopover and change of planes At KUL airport.

Will I be required to pass through Immigration at KUL airport again or simply board the next flight?

Answer (score 3):

If both your flights are on Malaysia Airlines, **you do not need to pass through Immigration**, just board your next flight.

Comment: There is still security though!

Comment: KUL has security at the gates, but they don't need a visa!

Comment: No visa, no, but you do need to allow extra time to get through the at-gate security, so it's not quite as simple as "just board"

Comment: No, you don't really need to allow extra time, just show up before the gate closes.  If there's a queue at the gate, they're still boarding and you're OK; if there is no queue, you can either waltz in, or you've already missed your flight.

Comment: Having done this recently traveling from Beijing to Krabi, Thailand, I can verify that this answer is correct. And even if you do need to change airlines, the international terminals are mostly connected. My girlfriend and I simply had to pass through a line where they re-checked our tickets before we could enter the departure terminal from the one we landed at.